# After running "opkg install tcpdump" on tp-link router flashed OpenWrt successfully, the tcpdump command doesn't work

Tags: router, tcpdump, openwrt, opkg

I am doing a wireless experiment which used a tp-link router WR1043ND flashed OpenWrt system. Because I need to catch packages through the router, I need to install the tcpdump software.
I just used the command **"opkg install tcpdump"** to install it, and the terminal showed installation successful.

But when I entered **"tcpdump"** command, I got a failure prompt which showed that

> -ash: tcpdump: not found

So I try to know whether the tcpdump was installed. I entered as following:

> opkg list | grep tcpdump

the result after filter showing:

``` openvswitch-ovs-tcpdump - 2.8.1-1 - Dump traffic from an Open vSwitch port using tcpdump
openvswitch-ovs-tcpundump - 2.8.1-1 - Convert ``tcpdump -xx`` output to hex strings
pcapsipdump - 0.2-1 - pcapsipdump is a tool for dumping SIP sessions (+RTP traffic, if available) to disk in a fashion similar to "tcpdump -w" (format is exactly the same), but one file per sip session (even if there is thousands of concurrect SIP sessions).
tcpdump - 4.9.2-1 - Network monitoring and data acquisition tool
tcpdump-mini - 4.9.2-1 - Network monitoring and data acquisition tool (minimal version)
tcpreplay - 4.2.5-1 - tcpreplay is a tool for replaying network traffic from files saved with tcpdump or other tools which write pcap(3) files. ```

Obviously, the installation was successful. 
I really hope somebody can help me handle this question, thanks!